# Can Several Computers be Used as One?

Tags: pi-3

I was wondering if it is possible to link several computers, such as a raspberry pi, and have them share resources; acting like one, more powerful, computer. If so, how would it be accomplished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but because of low power of Rpi, they are used for educational/testing purposes only. For serious tasks (parallel computing, load balancing) they are inefficient when compared to regular server.
Have a look on these sites or search in Google for "Raspberry Pi cluster".

[Pros and Cons of a Pi Cluster?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14973/pros-and-cons-of-a-pi-cluster)

http://makezine.com/projects/build-a-compact-4-node-raspberry-pi-cluster/

https://resin.io/blog/what-would-you-do-with-a-120-raspberry-pi-cluster/